# How to include sound in app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am developing an application in which I input text; when I hit enter it will speak. Does anyone know any sound engine or source code I should include so that it will talk? I have been trying to make this for the last four months but am not able to get it working. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [FLITE](http://artofsystems.blogspot.com/2009/02/speech-synthesis-on-iphone-with-flite.html)? It's easy to use and works quite well.

Comment: Glad it worked. Could you tick the green check next to my answer to indicate that the answer helped you? Thanks!